# MinGW env path (CMD) doesn't catch all my C errors

Tags: c, ubuntu, mingw

I was creating a C program of a Phonebook, and when coming to compile and run time, I was using command prompt and the MinGW path to compile and run my program. All of a sudden, in runtime, my program would crash. Using printf statements to find out whether or not my program reached a certain point (Maybe I could've used gcc debugger but not sure), I would find out that my program would reach certain points but not others. I also have an Ubuntu terminal to use valgrind to check for memory leaks, and so I used gcc and voila I receive errors that weren't found on the command prompt execution of the same gcc prompt

for example in my code

```
char *pNumber = malloc(11*sizeof(char));

    char term;
    bool valid = false;
    while (!valid) {
        printf("enter phone number (first 10 digits will be parsed)\n");
        int scan = scanf("%s%c", &pNumber, &term);
    
...
...
...
```

there is an error in the scanf definition of a string to be a char pointer, as the correct definition should be

```
int scan = scanf("%s%c", pNumber, &term);
```

without the & sign for pNumber

but this doesn't get printed in trying to compile using gcc main.c -o main (cmd)

when using ubuntu terminal, I get

```
main.c: In function ‘addTelephoneNumber’:
main.c:119:25: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char **’ [-Wformat=]
  119 |      int scan = scanf("%s%c", &pNumber, &term);
      |                        ~^     ~~~~~~~~
      |                         |     |
      |                         |     char **
      |                         char *
```

most of the time errors are detected from cmd, but I was confused how this was a blatant error that shouldn't have made it to runtime

Is there something wrong with my Windows environment variable? Or anything else I'm not quite sure

Thanks for any help

Comment: As you demonstrated, it is not an error that prevents compilation, but rather a warning.

Comment: Add `-Wall -Wextra` to your compile command. Even then a compiler is not required to warn about every possible thing.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the exact command lines you use on Windows and Ubuntu.